# How to generate adding coupons in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I need to do a sum to generate coupons for a promotion, every customer gets $ 200 one (1) coupon, let's assume that he register $ 1000 ... he would be entitled to five (5) coupons and so on, how can I get the amount spent by the customer base and generate coupons diso according to the value?

Thank you!

Comment: You will need a server database. Also, it would be good to use ASP.NET

Comment: Could you show your working of the problem so far? Some better examples? It would show that you have tried to solve it, and need help with the programming, rather than asking for help with the problem instead of the coding.

Comment: The calculation would be Int(registerAmount / 200). As for how you would generate coupons well that's a whole other story.